# NetUserGetInfo fails

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using the following code to run the [NetUserGetInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
bool MyGetComputerName(std::wstring &ComputerName) {
    bool bReturn=false;
    WCHAR ComputerNameBuffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1]={0};
    DWORD dwComputerNameLength=MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1;
    DWORD dwReturn=GetComputerNameExW(ComputerNameNetBIOS,ComputerNameBuffer,&dwComputerNameLength);
    if(dwReturn) {
        ComputerName=std::wstring(ComputerNameBuffer);
        bReturn=true;
    }
    return bReturn;
}
std::wstring ComputerName;
MyGetComputerName(ComputerName);
USER_INFO_1003* pUserInfo=0;    
NetUserGetInfo(ComputerName.c_str(),L"Gast",1003,reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE*>(&pUserInfo));
```

The function NetUserGeInfo fails and returns the error 124. GetLastError returns error 997.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the documentation for the 1003 structure? No mention of it here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654(v=vs.85).aspx .  Found it only valid for `NetUserSetInfo` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370963(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which structure should I use with  if I want to determine wherther an user account is disabled or not?

Comment: Took me 30 secs following the links in the 1st link in comment.

Comment: It will work, if I use USER_INFO_1* as Buffer.

Comment: Yes, it's working.

Comment: `NetUserGetInfo` doesn't set the last error code. Calling `GetLastError` is thus meaningless.

Comment: @HansPassant: "*you need a buffer, not a pointer*" - read the documentation: "*`bufptr` [out] A pointer to the buffer that receives the data. The format of this data depends on the value of the `level` parameter. **This buffer is allocated by the system and must be freed using the `NetApiBufferFree` function**.*" So you have to pass a *pointer to a pointer*. `NetUserGetInfo()` will allocate a suitable buffer and update your pointer to point at it, then you can use it and free it.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm: "*Which structure should I use with if I want to determine wherther an user account is disabled or not?*" - use `USER_INFO_1`, its `usri1_flags` field will contain the `UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE` flag if the account is disabled.

Comment: Thank you. I have used the USER_INFO_1 structure and it has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third argument to `NetUserGetInfo` is completely invalid, which is why it's returning error 124 (`ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL`).

Pass a number within the range specified in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654(v=vs.85).aspx) for the `level` parameter if you expect it to work. In this case you should be passing the value 1.

Comment: It will work, if I pass the value 1 as third argument.

Comment: "*All I can figure is `NetUserGetInfo` is only looking at the low bits of level and returning a `USER_INFO_3`*" - no, it doesn't.  The fact that it is returning error 124 proves that, because error 124 is `ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL`, which means it is completely rejecting 1003 as an input value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, I overlooked the error info in the question. Edited appropriately.